# How do I disable an MUI MenuItem in a mapped table by reading an item in the table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a table that has a mapped object:

```
{users.map((user,index) => {
 <TableRow key={index}>
 ...
```

That last cell of the table is a button that that is connected to an MUI Menu. One of the menu items needs to be disabled if a certain aspect of a user is true, but every method I've tried to do so just disables that MenuItem for every user in the table. Debugging shows that the page goes through the page twice and sets every to disabled.

```
<TableCell>
  <Box>
    <PlainButton
      id='userActionsButton
      aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
      aria-haspopup='true'
      aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
      onClick={handleActionButtonClick}
    >Actions<ExpandMoreIcon/></PlainButton>
    </Box>
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl} 
      open={openActionMenu} 
      onClose={handleActionMenuClose} 
      MenuListProps={{'aria-labelledby' : 'userActionsButton'}}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleOpenPasswordModal} 
        **disabled={user.userType === 'disabled'}**
      >Option to disable</MenuItem>
```

If any userType is 'disabled', then every single button on the table becomes disabled, rather than just the disabled users. I've tried pulling the check out of the map with something similar to:

```
const disableCheck = (user) => { if (user.userType === 'disabled') ...
```

but this just brings the same result.

I'm not sure what other info I would need to provide to make this clearer, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by making separate component for menu.

```
const MenuList = ({ user }) => {

   const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

   const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
   const handleClick = (event) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
   };
   const handleClose = () => {
      setAnchorEl(null);
   };


  return (
    <div>
        <Button
            id="basic-button"
            aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            Action
        </Button>
        <Menu
            id="basic-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            MenuListProps={{
                'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
            }}
        >
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}
                disabled={your-condition}
            >
                Profile
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and calling it inside `TableCell` as:

```
 <TableCell align="right">
    <MenuList user={user} />
 <TableCell />
```

Issue is maybe related to `anchorEl`, separating the component will have its own `anchorEl` state for each row.